# Routing Slip Spring Integration (4.2)

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-messaging

I am trying to implement routing slip (EI Pattern) using Spring integration. The configuration I have done is

```
 @Bean
    @Transformer(inputChannel = "routingServiceChannel")
    public HeaderEnricher headerEnricher() {
        return new HeaderEnricher(Collections.singletonMap(IntegrationMessageHeaderAccessor.ROUTING_SLIP,
                new RoutingSlipHeaderValueMessageProcessor("routingChannel2",                   
                    "routingChannel1")));
    }
```

So when it reaches routingServiceChannel, it goes to routingChannel2 and then routingChannel1. But in my case it always throws an exception that it does not have a reply channel. when I set output channel, like

```
@Transformer(inputChannel = "routingServiceChannel", outputChannel=""xyzChannel)
```

Then then routing happens to xyzChannel instead of going to routingChannel2, and routingChannel1.

When I debugged the code in spring integration core, I stumbled with this code,
In

class AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler

```
protected final void handleMessageInternal(Message<?> message) {
        Object result;
        if (this.advisedRequestHandler == null) {
            result = handleRequestMessage(message);
        } else {
            result = doInvokeAdvisedRequestHandler(message);
        }
        if (result != null) {
            sendOutputs(result, message);
        } else if (this.requiresReply) {
            throw new ReplyRequiredException(message, "No reply produced by handler '" + getComponentName()
                    + "', and its 'requiresReply' property is set to true.");
        } else if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
            logger.debug("handler '" + this + "' produced no reply for request Message: " + message);
        }
    }
```

Here in handle message method they obtain the routingSlip map and assigning it to the result. 
And

```
protected void produceOutput(Object reply, Message<?> requestMessage) {
        MessageHeaders requestHeaders = requestMessage.getHeaders();

        Object replyChannel = null;
        if (getOutputChannel() == null) {
            Map<?, ?> routingSlipHeader = requestHeaders.get(IntegrationMessageHeaderAccessor.ROUTING_SLIP, Map.class);
            if (routingSlipHeader != null) {
                Assert.isTrue(routingSlipHeader.size() == 1, "The RoutingSlip header value must be a SingletonMap");
                Object key = routingSlipHeader.keySet().iterator().next();
                Object value = routingSlipHeader.values().iterator().next();
                Assert.isInstanceOf(List.class, key, "The RoutingSlip key must be List");
                Assert.isInstanceOf(Integer.class, value, "The RoutingSlip value must be Integer");
                List<?> routingSlip = (List<?>) key;
                AtomicInteger routingSlipIndex = new AtomicInteger((Integer) value);
                replyChannel = getOutputChannelFromRoutingSlip(reply, requestMessage, routingSlip, routingSlipIndex);
                if (replyChannel != null) {
                    // TODO Migrate to the SF MessageBuilder
                    AbstractIntegrationMessageBuilder<?> builder = null;
                    if (reply instanceof Message) {
                        builder = this.getMessageBuilderFactory().fromMessage((Message<?>) reply);
                    } else if (reply instanceof AbstractIntegrationMessageBuilder) {
                        builder = (AbstractIntegrationMessageBuilder<?>) reply;
                    } else {
                        builder = this.getMessageBuilderFactory().withPayload(reply);
                    }
                    builder.setHeader(IntegrationMessageHeaderAccessor.ROUTING_SLIP,
                            Collections.singletonMap(routingSlip, routingSlipIndex.get()));
                    reply = builder;
                }
            }

            if (replyChannel == null) {
                replyChannel = requestHeaders.getReplyChannel();
            }
        }

        Message<?> replyMessage = createOutputMessage(reply, requestHeaders);
        sendOutput(replyMessage, replyChannel);
    }
```

Instead of getting the routingSlip configuration from the reply, they are trying to get from the requestMessage. 
Am I missing something here? Are there any additional configuration that I need to set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for the attention to the subject, BTW! :)

Everything looks good, but you have missed the point of the Routing Slip.

First of all you should configure it for the message. And since Routing Slip is a `header` you should use `HeaderEnricher` to add it to the headers of the message.

The routing is really caused in the downstream from and exactly for the `requestMessage`, not the `reply`. The Routing Slip is out of `HeaderEnricher`.

Although it may happen for the `HeaderEnricher`'s `requestMessage`, of course.

If you would like to consult Routing Slip exactly after the `HeaderEnricher`, you should configure something like:

```
@BridgeTo
@Bean
public MessageChannel xyzChannel() {
    return new DirectChannel();
}
```

Note: no one *new* header is available during `HeaderEnricher` logic. Only in the downstream. And Routing Slip is one of them.

Comment: Thanks Artem for the quick response :), I will make the following changes and update you.